# Create a custom search for Estate Agency Wordpress site

Tags: customization, search

I'm currently working on an Estate Agency website. Built the custom post type and some custom taxonomies.

I need to build a custom search where a user can select options from the custom taxonomies to display the search results.

Example: Search by location & min-max price & number of bedrooms.

I tried a couple of plugins for Real Estate but they don't allow me enough control over the display of the output in the frontend of the website, therefore I need to build my own "simple" custom search.

Can anybody point me in the direction of a tutorial, or how to do this. I don't want to use a plugin as I can't find one that isn't overkill or gives me enough space to output what I need.

Hoping somebody can help

Thanks in advance

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Search and Filter plugin. My PHP isn't strong enough to build such a thing, when I was pushed for a deadline by the client. In the end, I had to use the plugin which works great, rather than trying to build my own.

Thanks for the help though guys, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it would be to build a custom html form and then use $_POST to actually perform a search based on inputs.

It's a bit broad of a topic to go into specifics though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a plugin called https://www.relevanssi.com/ They do a free version too, Very good plugin. You can set it to only search taxonomies if you want and use filters too. 
I know you said no plugins, but I would suggest this one. 
I was in same predicament as you for a directory website and ended up using this plugin. I know pretty much use for any sites needing custom search options.

Comment: Hi Chazlie, I would not answer with a recommendation for a plugin if he does want to use a plugin ....